# Sending multiple files one socket in python

Tags: python, file, sockets

I'm trying to send files (images and text) by sockets in python. I don't want to create a new connection every time because the code is writing lots of files (>100) in a short amount of time so I don't want to build up that many connections while they wait to close. So before each chunk of the file is sent, I send the length of the chunk first. When I run it, it gives me a ValueError on `length = int(s.recv(4))` , showing a string from the file and saying that it cannot be converted to an int. Here is the part of my code that sends and receives one file: 
Sending:

```
#Connect s and open file f
s.setblocking(1)
buf = 4096
while True:
    msg = f.read(buf)
    length = str(len(msg))
    if len(length) < 4: length = "0"*(4-len(length)) + length

    s.sendall(length)
    if length == "0000": break
    s.sendall(msg)
    if len(msg) != buf: break
```

Receiving:

```
#Connect s and open file f
while True:
    length = int(s.recv(4))
    if length == 0: break

    f.write(s.recv(length))
    if length < buf: break
```

Running on Windows 8.

Comment: use `socket.htonl` and `socket.ntohl` and send it as binary.

Comment: Could you please expand on this?

Comment: why couldn't use ftp or sftp?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending large files (depending on your router), the router might split the packets into shorter ones causing you to accidentally try to get the length of a chunk while still not getting the entire earlier file. You should make sure with a while loop that you got the entire length of data, if not keep requesting for the data with s.recv(length - len(what_i_got_so_far)).

Example, when I'm sending to myself a few MB picture through LAN the router cuts the packets to around 25 KB so I have to use recv a lot of times although I only used 1 send.

I hope this helps.